# Arrays indexOf in mongo using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array outside mongodb in a script, called **title**. And, I have a dataset with some fields I do not want **(Dataset_1)** inside mongodb.
I am creating an if indexOf for matching value in order to create a ranking.

**Dataset_1** looks like this.

```
geotype    state            numbers    
state      Alabama          14
state      Alaska           344
state      California       144
state      New York         255
state      Washington       233
state      Guam             255
state      Puerto Rico      36
state      Virgin Islands   366
state      Delaware         434
state      New Mexico       444
state      Maryland         544
...
```

**var title** looks like this

```
var title = [            
'Alabama',         
'Alaska',           
'California',       
'New York',         
'Washington',       
'Delaware',         
'New Mexico',       
'Maryland'
...]
```

If you notice **var title** only has the US states not the territories.

My end goal is to rank the states by 'numbers' within a new column **'ranking'** if there is a match with **title** array. If there is no match I do not want it to be ranked. For example I do not want Guam and Puerto Rico to ranked.

```
if (Dataset_1[column].indexOf(title) > -1) {
    execute 
}
```

Here is my ranking JS code with mongodb dataset update.

```
//This is my script which also contains var title.
var rank = 0;
var rank_value = Infinity;
db.Dataset_1.find({'geo_type': 'state'}).sort({'numbers': -1}).forEach(function(doc){
    if (doc['state'].indexOf(title) > -1) { 

    if (doc['numbers'] < rank_value) {
        rank_value = doc['numbers']; 
        rank = rank + 1;
    }
    if (doc['numbers'] != null) {
        db.Dataset_1.update({
            '_id' : doc['_id']
        },{$set: {
            'ranking' : rank
        }})
    }
    }
});
```

This code ranks all the fields disregarding the indexOf I have set. Am I doing the indexOf function correctly?

I have tried it many different ways. Either I get a syntax error or unwanted fields.

To summarize here is an example output.

```
geotype    state     numbers    ranking
state      Alabama   14         11
state      Alaska    344        5
...
```

Comment: That's a syntax error, it should be `if (Dataset1.indexOf(title) > -1) { ...`

Comment: I've corrected that syntax. But, this will not go through the 'state' column which needs to be ranked. Because it is not defined as such. If you see my my function in the code doc['state'] it goes through the 'state' column in Dataset_1 to match with var title.

Comment: @OmarA title is an array. Your doc has state as a string. Do you want to see if state lies in the list of titles?

Comment: @ayushgp Yes, precisely. If state isn't in the title I would not want it ranked.

Comment: @OmarA  Does my new edit solve your problem?

Comment: @ayushgp Yes it did. Terrific. Cannot believe it was that type of mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
if (Dataset1.indexOf(title > -1)) {
    execute 
}
```

It should be: `if(Dataset1.indexOf(title) > -1)`

**EDIT**:

You want to check if the state lies in list of titles, then you'll need to have:

```
if(title.indexOf(doc['state']) > -1)
```

instead of

```
if (Dataset1.indexOf(title) > -1)
```

Comment: I've corrected it. After running it it stills ranks all the entities inside 'state' of Dataset_1.